# Merge columns with different number of rows based on two first columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different files containing the same number of columns but different lengths, i.e,

file1.txt

```
1650,A,1,1,1
1650,A,1,1,1
1650,A,1,1,1
1650,B,2,2,2
1650,B,2,2,2
1650,B,2,2,2
1650,B,2,2,2
1650,B,2,2,2
```

file2.txt

```
1650,A,3,3,3
1650,A,3,3,3
1650,A,3,3,3
1650,A,3,3,3
1650,A,3,3,3
1650,B,4,4,4
1650,B,4,4,4
```

I want to concatenate both of them using pandas such that the result is as follows:

```
1650,A,1,1,1,3,3,3
1650,A,1,1,1,3,3,3
1650,A,1,1,1,3,3,3
1650,A,NaN,NaN,NaN,3,3,3
1650,A,NaN,NaN,NaN,3,3,3
1650,B,2,2,2,4,4,4
1650,B,2,2,2,4,4,4
1650,B,2,2,2,NaN,NaN,NaN
1650,B,2,2,2,NaN,NaN,NaN
1650,B,2,2,2,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

I use the following codes but it seems it does not work properly:

```
df1 = read_data('file1')
df2 = read_data('file2')
result = pd.merge_ordered(df1,df2, how='outer', on=['a', 'b'])
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, so possible merge by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with add column `group`:

```
df1['group'] = df1.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()
df2['group'] = df2.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()
result = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', on=['a', 'b', 'group']).drop('group', axis=1)
```